# Sorting with special characters at the end

Tags: javascript

I looked at an old thread and the answer I got wasn't really working, because of the special cases 'zz', 'ZZZ', etc.

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
     return a.replace(/^\W+/, 'z').localeCompare(b.replace(/^\W+/, 'z'));
});
```

So, I came up with my own tweaked version of it, which is:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
     return a.replace(/^\W+/, 'Ω').localeCompare(b.replace(/^\W+/, 'Ω'));
});
```

But I feel this is a very bad practice, because it's a hack. Is there a simpler, but more correct way of doing this?

Input:

```
 ['111', '-213', '_1231', 'aasda', 'zzadsa', '<da>']
```

Expected Output:

```
 ['111', 'aasda', 'zzadsa', '-213', '_1231', '<da>']
```

Comment: There's not enough here to reproduce your results.  Please show the actual call to the function that produces the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an arbitrary "large" character value like `Z` or `Ω`, you should use the maximum code unit:

```
 var last = String.fromCharCode(0xFFFF);
 function ignoreSpecialChars(x) {
     return x.replace(/\W/g, last);
 }
 function compare(a, b) {
     a = ignoreSpecialChars(a);
     b = ignoreSpecialChars(b);
     return (a>b)-(b>a);
 }

 array.sort(compare);
```